# achartengine: Disable relative sizing in BubbleChart

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm using BubbleChartView in achartengine for android. I see that the Bubble Chart view relatively sizes the bubbles depending on the values it has to accommodate in the view with the highest value set to a fixed max bubble size. Is it possible to disable relative sizing and fix the size of a bubble for a given value irrespective of what values are present in the XYValueSeries?

I'm repainting the view based on some checkboxes and bubbles keep changing their size though they have the same value.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just use the values that are needed such as you get the desired bubble size?